# apkinfo is working on local but not working on aapanel

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, devops, node-modules

I have created a simple Post API, Where I received the name, nameSpace, image_icon, and apk_attachment from the frontend, and then inside the controller, I extract(using apkinfo module) packageName from apk_attachment and validate accordingly, from the below code you will have the idea.

HERE IS THE CONTROLLER FUNCTION:

```
const apkinfo = require('apkinfo');
const appData = async (req, res) => {
try {
    console.log('inside post controllers');
    const { name, nameSpace, status } = req.body;
    

   
    // Check if required fields are provided
    if (!name || !nameSpace || !req.files['apk_attachment'] || req.files['apk_attachment'].length === 0 || !req.files['icon_image']) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            error: 'Bad Request',
            message: 'All fields (name, namespace, apk_attachment, icon_image) are required.',
            data: null
        });
    }

    const iconImage = req.files['icon_image'] ? req.files['icon_image'][0].filename : null;
    const apkAttachment = req.files['apk_attachment'] ? req.files['apk_attachment'][0].filename : null;
    

    // Extract information from the uploaded APK file
    const apkFilePath = `uploads/${apkAttachment}`; 
    const apkInfo = await extractApkInfo(apkFilePath);
    
...rest of the code


 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    if (error.name === 'SequelizeDatabaseError' && error.message.includes('Data truncated')) {
        return res.status(400).json({ 
            success: false,
            error: 'Bad Request',
            message: 'One or more fields contain invalid data. Please check your input.',
            data: null
        });
    }

    return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        error: error,
        message: 'An unexpected error occurred | Internal Server Error',
        data: null
    });
}
```

}

> fucntion to extrect APK information using apkinfo

```
const extractApkInfo = async (apkFilePath) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    apkinfo.get(apkFilePath, (error, info) => {
        if(error) {
            console.error('Error in apkinfo.get:', error);
            reject(error)
        } else {
            console.log('APK Info from apkinfo.get:', info);
            resolve({
                appName: info.appName,
                packageName: info.packageName,
                versionCode: info.versionCode,
                versionName: info.versionName,
            });
        }
    });
});
```

};

> NOTE: without apk_attachment it returns 'All fields (name, namespace, apk_attachment, icon_image) are required.' because of the validation but with apk_attachemt it shows the below **ERROR** from catch block:

```
{
"success": false,
"error": {
    "killed": false,
    "code": 127,
    "signal": null,
    "cmd": "/www/wwwroot/deazitech.com/updater/node_modules/apkinfo/lib/aapt_linux d badging uploads/9be87de64c55cc4276c80e5a33ee601a"
},
"message": "An unexpected error occurred | Internal Server Error",
"data": null
```

}

> The same code on the local machine works perfectly fine.